# How to display a box of color beside a table row <tr> using CSS?

Tags: css, positioning

Is it possible to float a box of color to the left of a table row **without having to use an empty element?**

I'd like to get rid of the `<span></span>` in the first `<td>` and just use pure CSS if possible.

It should look something like this

[image: mockup]

---

Here's what I currently have:

```html
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td><span></span>float a box of any color to the left of this row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>it should be the same heieght as the row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>and 15 pixels wide</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```css
table {
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 25px;
}

table td {
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px;

}

/* can i achieve the same effect without having
   to rely on a <span> element? */
table td span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -20px;
    width: 15px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Play around with it on [cssdeck](http://cssdeck.com/labs/9osbozli)

Comment: depending on browser support requirements you could use a psuedo-element and a class. This won't work in IE<=7 though. I've forked your example: http://cssdeck.com/labs/jz94ijv1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the words of the great philosophers, the Beastie Boys, CH-CH-CHE-CH-CHECK IT OUT: http://cssdeck.com/labs/hxfa4xzz

Using just CSS's `:before` pseudo-selector and `content:` property, it's doable.

```
table {
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 25px;
}

table td {
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px;
}

table tr:first-child td:before {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -20px;
  width: 15px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: hot dog! that's the winning ticket.

Answer (score 1):

I've modified your example to show how it can be done with CSS :before, however this will not work in older browsers, but it means no extra mark up (Except a class to identify which row/column).

http://cssdeck.com/labs/08h7pcbn

You can modify it to apply it on the row instead of the cell, but I was keeping it as close to your example as possible.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I didn't notice that until you mentioned - it looks like something to do with the float, which can be fixed by doing what others have suggested with position absolute.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, if you want to stick with tabular formatting, I would just add another `<td>` to each row and apply a class to the `<td>`'s which you wanted to have that style.

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td class="green_box"></td>
        <td>float a box of any color to the left of this row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="clear_box"></td>
        <td>it should be the same heieght as the row</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="clear_box"></td>
        <td>and 15 pixels wide</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The trouble with this is it nudges the table over. I'd like to avoid this if possible. It also makes it hard to format borders/header styles for the rest of the table.